# is there any limit for using server_name domains in nginx?

Tags: nginx, dns, subdomain, server, virtualhost

I want point multiple domains to a nginx instance. I use server_name for pointing them.

```
server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com test.mydomain.com test1.mydomain.com;
```

is the above given is best practice or there's any other safe/stable method for doing the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define quite a lot `server_name`s (even a few thousand won't really slow it down). However, if you want your config to remain somewhat readable, you should either:

- use RegEx to match the HOST string to a server block
- use a default server to match everything not explicitly defined in
  other server
- blocks use wildcard `server_name`s

Keep in mind that using exact names are always faster than using wildcards or RegEx.

In case you want to stick to using a long list of server names, you should include an additional config file:

```
server {
    include /somewhere/server_names;
    ...
}
```

Add. file:

```
server_name
    mydomain.com 
    www.mydomain.com
    ...
```

See the [nginx docs on server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more info...

Comment: It works when using the absolute path of the file "server_name", Thanks!